# aspx page in module and ghosted web parts

Tags: web-part, web-template, provisioning, module

I am making a webtemplate. This webtemplate activates a hidden feature which contains a module, deploying the default.aspx page.

The module looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="salessiteFiles">
    <File Path="salessiteFiles\default.aspx" Url="default.aspx">
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

Inside the .aspx page, I have placed a webpart, defined like this:

```
<SalesWP:SalesWP runat="server" ID="g_b3f403fc_d209_45fd_be6f_6831c665aa1f" ....
```

When I create a site using my own template, the web part is present, but it appears to be 'ghosted' in some way; the WebPartManager can't find it, and if I open the default.aspx via SPD, the webpartzone is empty. I need to be able to access the webpart via a webpartmanager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should not to add web part to the page directly, instead of it you should use web part provision. You can start your research from this posts:

1. [Provisioning Custom WebPart in SharePoint 2010 tricks](http://aftabashaikh.com/2012/01/23/provisioning-custom-webpart-in-sharepoint-2010-tricks/)
2. [Provision a WebPart using a SharePoint Feature](http://platinumdogs.me/2009/08/04/provision-a-webpart-using-a-sharepoint-feature/)
3. [Provision publishing page with webpart in sandboxed solution](http://www.arnoldboersma.nl/post/2010/08/17/Provision-publishing-page-with-webpart-in-sandboxed-solution.aspx)

Comment: That appears to work! At first I wanted to avoid this method because I read a blog post saying that the ID property of the web parts didn't work (and I need that ID for the webpartmanager) but everything appears to be in order.